# Software that uploads a video to multiple video distribution channels?

Tags: video, youtube, video-recording, uploader, vimeo

What software options exist to upload a a video to multiple software distribution channels simultaneously?

For example, if I want to upload a video to YouTube, Vimeo, and several other options all at once.